# Reading a variable number of columns in R

Tags: r, text

I have a large tab-separated data file I am reading (in R) using:

```
read.delim(file, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Most of the lines have 6 columns, but some have extra columns with more text. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ThisTextIsOkay
1 2 3 4 5 ThisTextContinues InTheNextColumn
```

I would like to merge the last N columns into the last string field for column 6. I don't mind preserving the tab character in the resulting string.

Comment: Use `read.table` set `fill = TRUE` and combine the columns after the fact in R.

Comment: And there is no 'tab' character after the read operation. If you wanted a tab character to separate them then put them back in with `paste( ..., sep="\t")`

Comment: I should clarify that `read.delim` is probably _already_ using `fill = TRUE`, so you probably just need to `paste` the columns together after the fact.

Comment: Does it only continue until the next column, or do some of them spill over to 2, 3 more columns?

Comment: @GreenDemon OP does say "I would like to merge the last N columns into the last string field for column 6. "

Comment: Turns out that the excess columns were being read into the next row - perhaps because they were very long lines (>50000 characters in a single line). Weird. That said, `paste()` would solve the problem as described so please post it as an answer and I'll accept :)